# sql - multiple layers of correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

I have `table A, B and C`

I want to return all entries in table A that do not exist in table B and of that list do not exist in table C.

```
select * from table_A as a
where not exists (select 1 from table_B as b
where a.id = b.id)
```

this gives me the first result of entries in A that are not in B. But now I want only those entries of this result that are also not in C.

I tried flavours of:

```
select * from table_A as a
where not exists (select 1 from table_B as b
where a.id = b.id)
AND
where not exists (select 1 from table_C as c
where a.id = c.id)
```

But that isnt the correct logic. If there is a way to store the results from the first query and then select * from that result that are not existent in table C. But I'm not sure how to do that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `WHERE` clauses in (the external part of) your second query. That is not valid SQL. If you remove it, it should work as expected:

```
select * from table_A as a
where not exists (select 1 from table_B as b
                  where a.id = b.id)
AND
      not exists (select 1 from table_C as c            -- WHERE removed
                  where a.id = c.id) ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e760/2)** (thnx @Alexander)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from (
  select a.*, b.id as b_id, c.id as c_id 
  from table_A as a
  left outer join table_B as b on a.id = b.id
  left outer join table_C as c on c.id = a.id
) T
where b_id is null
  and c_id is null
```

Another implementation is this:

```
select a1.*
from table_A as a1
inner join (
  select a.id from table_A
  except  
  select b.id from table_B
  except
  select c.id from table_c
) as a2 on a1.id = a2.id
```

Note the restrictions on the form of the sub-query as described [here](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/except.php). The second implementation, by most succinctly and clearly describing the desired operation to SQL Server, is likely to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

how about using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableA a
        LEFT JOIN TableB b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN TableC c
            ON a.ID = c.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL AND
        c.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f2da/1)

Answer (score 2):

One more option with NOT EXISTS operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test71 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM (SELECT b.ID
                       FROM dbo.test72 b
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT c.ID
                       FROM dbo.test73 c) x
                 WHERE a.ID = x.ID
                 )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4100/1)

Option from @ypercube.Thank for the present;)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test71 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM dbo.test72 b
                 WHERE a.ID = b.ID  
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM dbo.test73 c
                 WHERE a.ID = c.ID
                 );
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e760/4)

Comment: Nice. You can add this variation on your answer, too: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b10f3/3)

Answer (score 1):

I do not like "not exists" but if for some reason it seems to be more logical to you; then you can use a alias for your first query. Subsequently, you can re apply another "not exists" clause. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( select * from tableA as a
  where not exists (select 1 from tableB as b
  where a.id = b.id) )
AS A_NOT_IN_B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tableC as c
  WHERE c.id = A_NOT_IN_B.id
)
```