# sql - confusion with correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery

I have been using suggestions given to me in an earlier question regarding subqueries. See here:

[sql - multiple layers of correlated subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073199/sql-multiple-layers-of-correlated-subqueries)

[SQL Server : left join results in fewer rows than in left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116559/sql-server-left-join-results-in-fewer-rows-than-in-left-table)

I am using ms sql server (I believe it is 2005).

What I am trying to do now is the following:

I have a result of rows (call it result A), that is obtained from doing the following:

```
select * from TableA as a
join (select * from TableB where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as b
on a.id = b.id
```

Of this result I want to find all rows that are NOT in the result of rows returned by this query:

```
select * from TableA as a
join TableC as c
on c.id = a.id
```

Essentially I have a situation where the first query results in 246 records, while the second query results in 247 records. I was expecting the first result to return 247 records (all of which should be in the list of records returned by the second query). So now I need to investigate which record is missing so I can take proper action.

I tried to do something like the following but received various errors:

```
select * from (select * from TableA as a
join (select * from TableB where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as b
on a.ul_id = b.id))
as result_A
where not exists (select 1 from (select * from TableA as a
                  join TableC as c
                  on c.id = a.ul_id) as result_B
                  where result_A.ul_id = result_B.id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this set difference:

```
select a.* from TableA as a
join TableC as c
on c.id = a.id

except

select a.* from TableA as a
join (select * from TableB where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as b
on a.id = b.id
```

If for some reason this does not return a row, then the first query has a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your narrative says you want to exclude results from:

```
select * from TableA as a
join TableC as c
on c.id = a.id
```

but your not exists has a different subquery.  Also, some of your errors may have been caused by using the same alias more than once.

Finally, Pieter's approach should work.  I didn't check the details.